# WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync not working

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, oauth-2.0, winrt-async

I am building a Windows 8 application and I'm trying to get a token from the Google data API when the application is starting. I built a function to do this, and it has the following code:

```
string authCodeUrl = UrlHelpers.BaseUrlFactory(UrlType.OAuth) +
                    "?client_id=" + _clientId +
                    "&redirect_uri=" + _redirectUri +
                    "&response_type=code" +
                    "&scope=" + _scope;

Uri startUri = new Uri(authCodeUrl);
Uri endUri = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?");

WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.UseTitle, startUri, endUri);
```

I'm calling the function in my App.xaml.cs `OnLaunched()`, before the `Window.Current.Activate()` call. The reason I am doing this is because I already need the token in my `MainViewModel`.

The strange thing is: when I launch my application the normal way (via Visual Studio) it gets stuck at the splashscreen (the splashscreen stays on for ages), but when I place a breakpoint on this line:

```
WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.UseTitle, startUri, endUri);
```

and step through it, I suddenly get a log in window that allows me to log in and obtain a token, meaning that the splashscreen goes away and I can use my application.

When I remove the call from my App.xaml.cs and just request the token from my ViewModel, I have the same problem: it's still stuck on the SplashScreen. I also have this problem when I do request a token from my App.xaml.cs but move the request after the `Window.Current.Activate()` call. But in these cases, the splashscreen goes away after logging in, but the screen stays black. I don't see my app.

P.s., this is how I request the token from my App.xaml.cs (`OnLaunched` is marked as `async`):

```
IOAuth2Service oAuth2Service = new OAuth2Service();
await oAuth2Service.GetToken();
```

OAuth2Service is just an object that has a method `GetToken()`. This method just does what I described above.

Does anyone know why it works when I step through the app with a breakpoint, but not when I just launch it without stepping through it?

I've isolated the problem and created a Github project that contains just this code. You can find it here: https://github.com/Avalaxy/OAuth2WinRT/tree/master/App1. There is an app.xaml.cs which calls OAuth2.GetToken().

Comment: any chance you could pull together as simple a repro as possible of this and post on dropbox or elsewhere (sans whatever app code you need for Oauth access).  There are potential subtleties in interpreting where your code is exactly, so it would save time to see it all failing locally.

Comment: @JimO'Neil You're right, I'll try to do that today.

Comment: @JimO'Neil I've updated the OP. I created a github repository that contains just this problem.

Comment: Moving Windows.Current.Activate before the call to GetToken seems to work ok in the sample (at least the dialog shows), but am trying to get a clearer understanding of why

Comment: @JimO'Neil Sweet! It does work indeed, but I don't know why. This is one of those things I wouldn't have found out, even if I kept on trying for days. Can you submit this as an answer so I can give you your credits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.activate.aspx) -

> If the app or its splash screen is kept on screen there is no time limit, but eventually the app **needs to call Activate to progress.**

Admittedly a bit vague and subject to interpretation, but moving the call to activate prior to the `GetToken` request will get you past what seems like a potential race condition.

Comment: thank you.. you saved me. i wasted almost 2 days over this issue. Any clue why is it happening? :/